# Using javascript to deny access from proxy sites to tumblr blog

Tags: javascript, redirect, proxy, tumblr

So I got a person who's been accessing my tumblr for over two months and sending me threats and insults every single day, multiple times a day. They are using proxy sites to access my blog, and IP blocking does not work because they use a different one every couple days. Is there a way to block access to anyone coming from a proxy site using javascript or something else that will work on tumblr? I'm not using my own domain, so my options are limited.

I've tried this fix here and it didn't work: http://joshtronic.com/2013/04/08/blocking-proxy-sites-with-javascript/
All it does is redirect everyone to the new address, regardless of the user coming through a proxy site or not.

Comment: When you say accessing, do you mean, leaving unsavory comments, or, actually adjusting the authored content of the blog?  Are the threats done by commenting?  Is turning off anonymous comments a potential solution, or is that undesirable?

Comment: They're leaving comments. Turning anon off didn't work, they just use blank blog accounts. I'm not even sure if this is one person or multiple people, this is why I'd like to just prevent them from seeing the blog at all.

Comment: Not JS, but are you in a position to open the htaccess file? [this for htaccess](http://perishablepress.com/how-to-block-proxy-servers-via-htaccess/) and [this for PHP](http://perishablepress.com/block-tough-proxies/) may be two options, though I haven't tried either of them.  Good luck and don't let the bastards get you down!

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. Tumblr is trash, I don't have access to the htaccess file and it doesn't support PHP. =(